# ostream operator << error C++

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

I am trying to figure out a way to fix this error for hours and sadly I haven't found any question asked here that would find me a solution.
This is a circular array. The node is made of 3 members: the data i input, the description I input and the age of the node is oldage.
here is my code:

```
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, Ringnode &node)
    {
        return os << "ringnode(age: " << node.oldage
                << ", description: " << node.des
                << ", data: " << node.symdata << ")";

}
```

des and symdata are string private members in class ringnode but oldage is an integer.
The error i am getting is the following: binary 'operator' : **no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'type' (or there is no acceptable conversion).**

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE] so we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: How are you using your operator?

Comment: `Ringnode &node` should probably be `const Ringnode &node`.

Comment: i edited it, sorry!

Comment: my operator is supposed to cout strings and cout the integer

Comment: const Ringnode &node isnt working either. The problem seems to be with converting to string and I really have no clue how to fix it. I have searched and tried for hours

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), [take the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and learn how to create a [Minimal, **Complete**, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I also recommend you [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) as well as checking [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: @SaraAbdelRahim The comment about `const` was not related to the question, just some advice. I'll repeat my first comment : please post [MCVE]. You aren't likely to get an actual answer until you do.

Comment: @SaraAbdelRahim Do `node.oldage` `node.des` `node.symdata` have overloaded `<<`? Are they simple types?

Comment: I made them as simple types

Comment: Try changing the parameter to `Ringnode const& node`. Try putting `return os;` on its own line.

Answer (score 1):

you normally do

that as a `friend` and implemented like:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Ringnode& node)
{
        os << "ringnode(age: " << node.oldage
                << ", description: " << node.des
                << ", data: " << node.symdata << ")";
      return os;
}
```

Comment: @SaraAbdelRahim • it works on my machine, after I added the relevant `#include` and mocked up a Ringnode struct.  In what way doesn't it work on your machine?

Comment: @SaraAbdelRahim • I think the bug is in the code you did not provide.  Could you provide a minimal, complete, compilable example code that reproduces the problem?  By "complete" I mean I can just copy-and-paste it into my own source file, and compile it on my machine, as is, without having to guess about the code not provided.  That would help us a lot to help you.